# DB Design, To normalize or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, database-design, entity-framework-4, nopcommerce

Using MS visual studio 2012, Asp.net C# MVC 4,  Entity Framework, **NopCommerce(cms)**.

Hi guys I have  Database Design Query, its actual confused me, normally I have no problems with DBs.

However since transitioning over to the **Code First approach** I asked my self this question...

I am Creating a new plugin for my NopCommerce CMS website,  This plugin shall be a **ImageGallery Plugin**.

I would like the Data layer to store an

```
ID,
Name,
LargeImg
SmallImg,
Urlimg
```

But I also want to realize the functionality of this Plugin, The user should be able to **upload any image and then Associate this image to a section** of there choosing,  What i mean by this is Img to a blog post, or Img to  news post, Img to a product post OR all of the 3.

Now these three examples are the only ones i can think of, but as you have guessed this may change depending on **additional content types**.

Now Instantly I thought, Easy we simply create a field called.....Type? or ContentType?
this field will then store the "type" of image association, whether it is a Blog, news or product item.

At which point i thought of "but what if an image has multiple associations?

To which brings me to the question, in this situation, Should i:

- Create **Separate Columns** for each "content Type" (non Normalized)
- Create **1 Column** Called "content-type" (normalized)
- Create a completely **Separate table** Called "content-types" and use relation

For some reason I'm stuck, I don't normally draw a blank on DB design and implementation.

The code below is my Domain Class in my plugin, i went for **number 2** but im not sure to continue down this road.

```
using Nop.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hroc.Plugin.Misc.ImageGallery.Domain
{
    public class ImageItem : BaseEntity
    {
        public virtual int ImageID { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual byte[] Largeimg { get; set; }
        public virtual byte[] Smallimg { get; set; }
        public virtual string URLimg { get; set; }
        public virtual string Typeimg { get; set; }
        public virtual int LinkID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

hopefully you guys can point out the correct way to implement this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With everything there is a trade-off

Benefits of normalization in your case:

- Extensibility - adding another content type requires no structure/class change
- Smaller tables (with variable-length data the difference may not be significant)

Drawbacks:

- Querying - if you need to pull multiple types in one query you'll need to de-normalize.
- Integrity Overhead - possibility of orphaned data if not managed properly

If I were designing this feature I would go with Option 3 - normalizing the content types has other advantages such as being able to use that table for drop-down lists.

Comment: simple answer, clean advice! I agree the advantages of normalization usually beats anything else.  Creating a separate entity for the content types whilst normalizing seems the best solution, though as you said Querying doesnt worry me as such, but Integrity Overhead is a worry, normalizing in this case seems to create the possibility complication,  What would you say is the best Manageable solution? Have i missed one out? or would you still stick to option 3 as the better evil?

Comment: I would stick with option 3 and just manage referential integrity.